# kotlin retrofit-Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65326(1448KB) AllocSpace objects, 62(1736KB) LOS objects,

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sticky

I'm trying to make a simple REST request with Retrofit in kotlin and i'm getting a lot of GC errors. I really don't know how to fix it. I tried to put more memory on emulator but the problem still happens.

My Code is:

```
    val retrofit =Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("Url")   
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
      .build()

    val retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java) 

    val call = retrofitAPI.getBarcharts(dashboardRequestBean)  
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseChartModel<BaseChartModel>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseChartModel<BaseChartModel>>? , response: Response<ResponseChartModel<BaseChartModel>>?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseChartModel<BaseChartModel>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
```

interface ApiServices

```
  @POST("getDashlet")fun getBarcharts(@Body dashboardRequestBean: DashboardRequestBean): Call<ResponseChartModel<BaseChartModel>>
```

Exception:

```
 FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 216
 06-15 09:16:14.928 6920-6931/ssa.abc.alrais.kotlindemo I/art: 
 Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65326(1448KB) 
 AllocSpace objects, 62(1736KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 
 5.406ms total 36.953ms
 06-15 09:16:15.118 6920-6931/ssa.abc.alrais.kotlindemo I/art: 
 Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 69034(1527KB) 
 AllocSpace objects, 72(2008KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 
 5.698ms total 65.069ms
 06-15 09:16:15.340 6920-6931/ssa.abc.alrais.kotlindemo I/art: 
 Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 75548(1650KB) 
 AllocSpace objects, 70(1960KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 
 6.638ms total 49.777ms
 06-15 09:16:15.559 6920-6931/ssa.abc.alrais.kotlindemo I/art: 
 Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 79831(1715KB) 
 AllocSpace objects, 71(2MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 
6.345ms total 75.652ms
```

Comment: But it's not an exception, it's just garbage collector logs

Comment: ok..solution please..

Comment: A solution for what? It's not a problem, it's just logging. 
Android always shows GC logs.
Maybe you have too many allocations, maybe not. You can check what's going on with memory using Android Studio memory monitor and allocation tracker.
BTW It's not Kotlin related

Comment: can I get complete structure of ResponseChartModel<BaseChartModel>

Comment: class ResponseChartModel: BaseResponse() {
          var content: BaseChartModel? = null
          }

Comment: open class BaseChartModel {

    var selectedId: Int? = null
    var chartMeasures: List<ListItem>? = null
    var chartContent: List<*>? = null
    var userInteraction: Boolean? = null
    @SerializedName("multitabEnabled")
    var isMultitabEnabled: Boolean = false
}

Comment: please add import statement of BaseChartModel

Comment: BaseChartmode:import android.app.LauncherActivity.ListItem,
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.app.LauncherActivity.ListItem is using for Displays a list of all activities which can be performed for a given intent. Launches when clicked.

So Please check your ListItem bean package.

Comment: Thanks asnad.its just mistaken.i am new in android